# How can I sort the dictionary by its value?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I used to obtain the sorted list by

```
dicttmp = {5:2, 2:5, 4: 3}
sorteddata = sorted(dicttmp.iteritems(), key = lambda d : d[1])
```

in python 2.7.
From the code above, I could obtain a list, every pair of key and value in `dicttmp` composes a tuple as a element in the list, and the list is ordered by the `value` of `dicttmp`.

But now, I install python 3.3, I learned that the method `iteritems()` is not supported any longer in the users' manual. How could I obtain a list or make the `dicttmp` sort by its `value`?

Could anyone help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Check http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: @sebastian That sounds like an answer if you extract the main points from it.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected my code. Could you help me again?@MaximeLorant

Comment: Why not using `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()` in python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.iteritems()` was removed, just use `dict.items()` instead:

```
sorteddata = sorted(dicttmp.items(), key=lambda d: d[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, `iteritems()` no longer exists; the `items()` method itself returns an iterator, and the only way to get a list of the items is to explicitly create one with `list(dicttmp.items())`.

In addition, you might want to use the `itemgetter` function from the `operator` module to supply the `key` function. It's a little more efficient than using a lambda expression.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_data = sorted(dicttmp.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

One proposal is to use [ordered](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) dict:

from the examples:

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by length of the key string
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])
```